# Laravel problem with saving into database

Tags: laravel, save, crud, store

I have a problem with Laravel CRUD
When im trying to add something to database nothing happen.
Everything just freeze on /note/store

[F12 result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4DrR.png)

I think there are some problems with $note->save(); in store function.
It is also important to mention that redirect in store function (NoteController) also doesnt work.

Controller:

```
 <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Note;

class NoteController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $notes = Note::all();
    // var_dump($cele);
    return view('note.index')->with('notes', $notes);
    }

    
    public function create()
    {
        return view('note.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required',
            'subtitle' => 'required',
            'content' => 'required',
            'color' => 'required',
            'tag' => 'required'
          ]);
      
          $current_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

         
          $note = new Note;
          $note->name = $request->input('name');
          $note->subtitle = $request->input('subtitle');
          $note->content = $request->input('content');
          $note->color = $request->input('color');
          $note->tag = $request->input('tag');
          //$note->created_at = $current_date;
          //$note->updated_at = $current_date;
          $note->save();

          return redirect()->route('/index')->with('success','dodano');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Note extends Model
{
 use HasFactory;

 public $table = "notes";
 public $timestamps = true;

 protected $fillable = [
     'name',
     'subtitle',
     'content',
     'color',
     'tag'
 ];
}
```

web.php

```
    <?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\NoteController;



//Route::get('/', function () {
   // return view('welcome');
//});

Auth::routes();

//Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');


//Route::get('/', 'NoteController@index');

Route::resource('note', NoteController::class);


Route::post('/note/store', function () {
    return back()->withInput();
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/note', [App\Http\Controllers\NoteController::class, 'index'])->name('note');
Route::get('/note/create', [App\Http\Controllers\NoteController::class, 'create'])->name('create');
Route::post('/note/store', [App\Http\Controllers\NoteController::class, 'store'])->name('store');
//Route::get('/note/store', [App\Http\Controllers\NoteController::class, 'store'])->name('store');


//Route::get('note/create', array('uses' => 'NoteController@index', 'as' => 'note/create'));
```

migration:

```
    <?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateNotesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('notes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('subtitle');
            $table->mediumText('content');
            $table->string('color');
            $table->string('tag');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        // Uzupełnienie tabeli rekordami
    DB::table('notes')->insert([
        [
            'name' => 'Notatka1',
            'subtitle' => 'Podtytuł',
            'content' => 'h3213',
            'color' => 'black',
            'tag' => 'notatka',
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'Notatka2',
            'subtitle' => 'Podtytuł',
            'content' => 'text',
            'color' => 'red',
            'tag' => 'notatka',
        ]
    ]);
    }

    

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('notes');
    }
}
```

Please,,, help;(

Comment: turn on debugging in env file and put `$note->save();` inside a try..catch block to check if it's throwing any exception

Comment: Please check also your error log at `storage/logs/laravel.log` if there is anything showing up.

Comment: Your `F12` output shows `PUT` as the method, but your routes are only set up for `POST` and `GET`

Comment: Ok its something wrong with routing, Ive added log on the start of store function and nothing shows.

Comment: But just changing POST on PUT in web.php isnt working.

Answer (score 0):

In your web.php file, there is no route /index. Are you sure you have a road of this name ?

Comment: You have two routes with the same URL "post('/note/store')". You must have unique URL routes.

Answer (score 0):

Ok its something wrong with routing, Ive added log on the start of store function and nothing shows.

My form in create.blade.php

```
<form
class="container"
action= "/note/store"
method="POST">
    {{ method_field('PUT') }}
    {{csrf_field()}}

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Nazwa</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Subtitle</label>
        <input type="text" name="subtitle" class="form-control">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Content</label>
        <input type="text" name="content" class="form-control">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Color</label>
        <input type="text" name="color" class="form-control">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Tag</label>
        <input type="text" name="tag" class="form-control">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-success">Zapisz</button>
    </div>

</form>

@endsection
```

I had to add {{ method_field('PUT') }}, because otherwise I get other error
"The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, PUT, PATCH, DELETE.""

How should I change my routes to make it work with PUT?

Answer (score 0):

Solved,

```
<form
class="container"
action= "/note"
method="POST">

    {{csrf_field()}}
    

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Nazwa</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Subtitle</label>
        <input type="text" name="subtitle" class="form-control">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Content</label>
        <input type="text" name="content" class="form-control">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Color</label>
        <input type="text" name="color" class="form-control">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Tag</label>
        <input type="text" name="tag" class="form-control">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-success">Zapisz</button>
    </div>

</form>

@endsection
```

Answer (score 0):

For the redirecting issue try to use the route name inside the route() for example

`redirect()->route('home')`